# A question on quantum tori

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $\mathbb T_\theta^2$ be quantum tori generated by two unitary operators $u,v$. can $u,v$ be finite dimensional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's fix conventions, so that $vu = e^{2\pi i \theta}uv$. It follows from a result of [Slawny](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103857742) that $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ is simple iff $\theta$ is irrational, so that $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ has a finite-dimensional representation only if $\theta$ is rational.

Now, suppose that $\theta = p/q$ for $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $U_{q}, V_{q} \in B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})) \cong M_q(\mathbb{C})$ by
$$
 \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}, \quad U_{q}\delta_m := e^{2\pi i m/q}\delta_m, \quad V_{q}\delta_m := \delta_{m+1},
$$
which are just the clock and shift operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{C}^q$. Then $U_q^p$ and $V_q$ are unitaries satisfying the commutation relation $V_q U_q^p = e^{2\pi i \theta} U_q^p V_q$, and hence
$$
 \pi_{p,q} : C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta) \to B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})), \quad \pi_{p,q}(u) := U_q^p, \quad \pi_{p,q}(v) := V_q
$$
gives you a $q$-dimensional unitary representation, whose image is called a “fuzzy [noncommutative] torus” in the mathematical physics literature. In fact, it follows from a result of [Høegh-Krohn–Skjelbred](https://eudml.org/doc/152389) that if $\theta = p/q$ in least terms, then $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ can be identified with the $C^\ast$-algebra of global sections of a locally trivial bundle of $C^\ast$-algebras over $\mathbb{T}^2$ with fibre $M_q(\mathbb{C})$.

---

**ADDENDUM**

The $C^\ast$-algebra $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$, which is the *universal* $C^\ast$-algebra generated by unitaries $u$ and $v$ satisfying $vu = e^{2\pi i \theta}uv$, is necessarily infinite-dimensional, and what the above (likely sub-optimal) argument shows is that it admits a finite-dimensional $\ast$-representation iff $\theta$ is irrational.

One way to construct $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ is as a strict deformation quantisation of $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$. This means that it is a certain $C^\ast$-completion of the $\ast$-algebra of trigonometric polynomials on $\mathbb{T}^2$ together with the deformed multiplication $$z_1^{m_1}z_2^{m_2} \star_\theta z_1^{n_1} z_2^{n_2} := e^{-\pi i \theta(n_1m_2-m_2 n_1)} z_1^{m_1+n_1}z_2^{m_2+n_2},$$
so that $u := z_1$ and $v := z_2$ with $v \star_\theta u = e^{2\pi i \theta}u \star_\theta v$. Since the vector space of trigonometric polynomials on $\mathbb{T}^2$ is literally untouched by this procedure, the infinite set $$\{z_1^{m_1}z_2^{m_2}\}_{(m_1,m_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} = \{e^{\pi i \theta m_1m_2}u^{m_1} \star_\theta v^{m_2}\}_{(m_1,m_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2}$$ remains linearly independent in the $C^\ast$-algebra $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$.

Comment: Good lord, I had no idea that the simplicity of the irrational rotation algebras was attributable to someone! I thought it was folklore.

Comment: Simplicity of the irrational rotation algebra qua crossed product is probably folklore. The necessary and sufficient condition for simplicity of a noncommutative $n$-torus is a special case of Slawny, and I fear I’m prejudiced to see a noncommutative $2$-torus first.

Comment: For $\theta$ irrational if we define a map $C(\mathbb T^2)\to \mathbb T_\theta^2$ as $z^mw^n\mapsto z^mU^mw^nV^n$ then this a unital injetive $*$-homomorphism. This will imply that $C(\mathbb T)$ is contained in a finite dimensional algebra which canot be possible since $C(\mathbb T)$ is infinite dimensional. This argument is also right?

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician I’m not entirely sure I understood your original question—I thought you were asking about representations, but it seems you were asking about infinite-dimensionality of $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ itself. In any event, note that the map your construct actually defines the canonical *action* of the topological Abelian group $\mathbb{T}^2$ on $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$ for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, but you need to know that $\{U^m V^n\}_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is linearly independent for this map to even be well-defined.

Comment: Is it not true that if you take two unitaries $u,v\subseteq B(\mathcal H)$ such that $uv=e^{2\pi\theta}vu$ then $\mathbb T_\theta^2$ is just the $C^*$-algebra generated by $u$ and $v$ in $B(\mathcal H)$?

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician Yes, but when people talk about the noncommutative or quantum $2$-torus $C(\mathbb{T}^2_\theta)$, they’re usually talking about the *universal* $C^\ast$-algebra with those generators and relations, so that having unitaries $u,v \in B(H)$ with $vu = e^{2\pi i \theta}uv$ is tantamount to a $\ast$-*representation* of the universal version. That said, be aware that the existence of a universal $C^\ast$-algebra with certain generators and relations is a delicate matter, unlike, say, defining a group in terms of generators and relations.